# Are there isometries of complex projective space which are not holomorphic?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, riemannian-geometry, complex-geometry

Consider complex projective space with the Fubini Studi metric. I am wondering if someone knows an explicit auto isometry which is not holomorphic / algebraic / linear. I'd also be curious about a non constructive proof of existence. Or are there none?

Comment: There are definitely isometries that are not holomorphic. In $n = 1$, under the identification of $\mathbb{CP}^1$ with $S^2$, you get a constant curvature metric. Under this identification, the holomorphic isometries correspond to orientation-preserving isometries of $S^2$ (namely, $\operatorname{SO}(3)$) while you also have non-holomorphic isometries that correspond to orientation-reversing isometries of $S^2$ (namely, elements in the full isometry group $\operatorname{O}(3)$ which don't belong to $\operatorname{SO}(3)$). I suspect this generalizes for $n > 1$.

Comment: @levap It does generalize to $\Bbb{CP}^{2n+1}$ - you can always take $(z_1, w_1, \dots, z_{n+1}, w_{n+1}) \mapsto (-\overline w_1, \overline z_1, \dots, -\overline w_{n+1}, \overline z_{n+1})$; this is an orientation-reversing isometry of $\Bbb C^{2n+2}$, restricts to an isometry of the unit sphere, respects multiplication by complex numbers, so descends to an isometry of $\Bbb{CP}^{2n+1}$. But as far as I can tell, that's the only addition. $\Bbb{CP}^{2n}$ can never support orientation-reversing isometries, so no luck with that approach.

Comment: Any Killing field on a compact Kahler manifold is necessarily holomorphic, so the Lie algebras of the holomorphic isometry group and the isometry group are the same. So the difference is, at best, a finite group.

Comment: @MikeMiller Thanks. Can you give a reference for why Killing fields on compact Kahler manifolds are holomorphic? Or is it "obvious"?

Comment: @AreaMan The Killing field preserves $g$ and $\omega$ is parallel with respect to $g$, hence a harmonic form. It is a general fact that $\mathcal L_X \omega = 0$ whenever $\omega$ is harmonic and $X$ is killing (the point is that the action of the isometry group on the harmonic forms is the same as the action on the cohomology groups, but homotopic maps induce the same map on cohomology). Since $X$ preserves both $g$ and $\omega$ and these determine $J$, it also preserves $J$.

Comment: The Riemannian geometry tag is misleading. I presume you mean isometries of the *hermitian* metric. ... If you don't know it, check out Kobayashi's book *Transformation Groups*.

Comment: @TedShifrin Does the answer change if we consider isometries with respect to the real part of the Hermitian metric? But you are right that I am being sloppy... Thanks for the book suggestion.

Comment: @AreaMan Yes. The orientation-reversing isometries I and levap gave are not Hermitian isometries but are Riemannian isometries.

Comment: The antipodal map of $S^2$ changes the sign of the Kähler form, so does not preserve the hermitian metric, but does preserve the Riemannian.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks ... do you know a good (example driven, not to formula heavy) reference for Kahler geometry? All I know about the subject is from gossip, and that's clearly not good enough...

Comment: If you're comfortable with Riemannian geometry, Besse, "Einstein Manifolds", is a great intro.

Comment: @MikeMiller Thanks, will check it out.